# How to To Filter wp_enqueue_script() Scripts on Some Pages

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-script

I am using following code to add some scripts in WP pages like

```
function add_js() {
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'colorbox-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'img-loader', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/img-load.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'box-tanzim', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/tanzim.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'),'',true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js' );
```

but I don't want to add unnecessary scripts on some pages! for example I would like to have all of above scripts on `front-page.php` but on other pages I don't need last three scripts.

Can you please let me know how I can filter them?

Thanks

> Update

```
    $frondPage = get_option('page_on_front');
    if(is_page($frondPage) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wait.js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/wait.js', array('jquery'),'',true );   
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent adding a script to a specific WordPress page by checking if whether we are on that page or not `is_page($page_id)`:

```
function add_js() {
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'colorbox-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js', array('jquery'),'',true );

  $pages = array(1,2,32); // insert the pages ID where you don't want these scripts enqueued

  if( ! is_page($pages) ) {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'img-loader', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/img-load.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'box-tanzim', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/tanzim.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'),'',true );

  }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam but can you also let me know what the `is_singular()` is doing here?

Comment: Oh yes thanks totally got confused with `is_page_template()` which requires that. Drop `is_singular()` and everything will work fine. Editing the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks again, but I am having issue on adding a script only to front page! can you please take a look at the update? As you can see

Comment: I tried to get the `front-page.php` if by using `$frondPage = get_option('page_on_front');` but this is noy working!

Comment: Did you try `is_front_page()` ?

Comment: Oh Isee what was happening now, I didnt change the reading setting to use static page! sorry and thanks for great help it is working perfectly now

Comment: I get it. No worries. Perhaps this `'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) && is_front_page()` would be even better if it worked.